# What is the difference between activerecord's attribute and read_attribute?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm able to run both and it returns the same vale:

```
user = User.new(name:'John')
user.attributes['first_name']
=> 'John'
user.read_attribute('first_name')
=> 'John'
```

Is one more performant than the other? Are there cases where I would use one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` returns a hash of all attributes for the user and `['first_name']` just accesses the specified parameter of the hash, whereas `read_attribute` just returns the single parameter asked for. You don't really need either of those methods to access the name as this can be done which makes the code a lot cleaner:

```
user = User.new(name:'John')
user.name
=> 'John'
```